# Why is NSUserDefaults saying I'm adding a non-property-list object? It's just an NSArray with an NSDictionary, NSNumber and NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

[NSUserDefaults docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

My code:

```
        NSData *provisionData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&provisionStruct length:sizeof(provisionStruct)];
        NSDictionary *accountIndexToProvisionPairing = @{@(globalSelf.accountIndexBeingSetup): provisionData};

        NSMutableArray *newProvisionedDevices = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ProvisionedDevices"] mutableCopy];
        [newProvisionedDevices addObject:accountIndexToProvisionPairing];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newProvisionedDevices forKey:@"ProvisionedDevices"];
```

Yet I get this every time I run it:

> Attempt to set a non-property-list object (
>           {
>           0 = <8b48ea2d b326da4b 82311275 d7f81960 6f481b01 b4d5146e 5bfc58e3 3d85e98d>;
>       }

What am I doing that involves a non-property-list object? It's just an NSArray of NSDictionaries, holding an NSNumber and NSData. All valid according to the above paragraph.

Comment: Would make sense... can't use a NSNumber as a key?  Crazy.

Comment: what do you mean we can't use use NSNumber as a key? Isn't it also a property list? I want to know because I have a nsmutabledictionary os nsarrays of nsstring that crashs when I try to store it in userdefaults, the dictionary has nsnumber as keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDafults restrictions applies not only to values but also to keys. It seems that your `globalSelf.accountIndexBeingSetup` is an integer number so `@(globalSelf.accountIndexBeingSetup)` is a NSNumber. Try to use `[@(globalSelf.accountIndexBeingSetup) description]` as a key to check this guess.

Comment: Never use the value of `description` for something like this. It's output is undocumented and could change someday. As an example, this happened with `NSDate` a while ago.

Comment: Also happened with NSURL in 10.8/iOS6